# Sending starting from one ip address and receivig with another

Tags: linux, ubuntu, centos, linux-networking

Friends, I wanted to test my firewall traffic for certain situations and wondering whether I could do it with a single computer. I configured following IP addresses (single network card, 2 ip addresses) in my computer

```
192.168.1.50 
192.156.1.60
```

I configured following gateways (both of these are of my firewall) in my computer

```
 192.168.1.1
 192.156.1.1
```

I have one ftp server in my computer. It is accessible through `192.168.1.50` and `192.156.1.60`

I can open a terminal and open a ftp session with the command `ftp 192.156.1.60`

When I am issuing the above mentioned command, I would like to use the ip `192.168.1.50` for the ftp client and `192.156.1.60` for the ftp server and route the traffic through my firewall. i,e, 192.168.1.1 has to accept the client traffic and 192.156.1.1 has to send the server traffic back. No communication should occur between `192.168.1.50` and `192.156.1.60` without the firewall. Is this possible? Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you should not use public internet address for tests like this `192.156.1.60` is allocated to "USMC Network Operations Center".

Your scenario doesn't reflect typical firewall scenario. Since both of your addresses are local, traffic does not go through FORWARD chain.

[Netfilter packet flow image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YkwUi.png) shows that the packet will go via INPUT chains of the firewall and then it is delivered to local process.

INPUT / OUTPUT and FORWARD chains are behave somewhat different. Therefore it is best to test using FORWARD chain.

In order to test using FORWARD chain, you need to set up either virtual machines or containers to host the services and clients, and add the firewall between those.